# Symfony 3.4 RequestStack -> MasterRequest -> ClientIp

Tags: symfony, localhost, ip-address, symfony-3.4

I fully understand that I test it on my localhost, but i wonder if it should return the real IP of my laptop or like actually a loopback '**::1**' in each of the following cases... Will it work differently in production or do I miss a point?

**From a controller**

```
 <?php

namespace SD\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as OriginalController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class SecurityController extends OriginalController
{
  public function loginAction(Request $request)
  {
    $clientIp = $this->get('request_stack')
       ->getMasterRequest()
       ->getClientIp()
    ;

    if($this->get('sd_user.ip_foresight')->isBlackListed($clientIp))
    {
      return new RedirectResponse(
        $this->generateUrl('sd_user_forbidden')
      );
    }

    return parent::loginAction($request);
  }

}
```

**From a listener**

```
<?php

namespace SD\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class IpListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
  protected $requestStack;

  public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
  {
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
  }

  public function clientIp()
  {
    return $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest()->getClientIp();
  }

  // ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it the right way. Let's see where IP address comes from:

1. Client's browser makes request to http://example.com.
2. Web-server catches request and its information like IP adress, headers, etc..
3. Web-server forwards this request to backend (symfony) and passes request infromation.
4. Symfony starts execution process from filling out master `Request` object with infromation that web-server provided.

So in the end you get `real` client IP address, not the one that was overridden by some action that called subrequest.

But there is one exception when you are using load balancer, in this case just read official documentation:

[How to Configure Symfony to Work behind a Load Balancer or a Reverse Proxy](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html)

Comment: Might also point out that it is trivial for the client to spoof an IP address so blocking will not deter a determined user.

Comment: @vadimashikhman : For now, I haven't decided to use a proxy, but the details of your answer help me a little more. So i guess there is no way to get a different result than '::1' from my laptop. Thank you.

Comment: @cerad : My idea here is to prevent a simple user already registered to access the connected part of my site, by collecting its IP at each connection, if bad behavior occurs, such as very rude comments for example, I reserve the right to block this person. Obviously it's limited.

Comment: @SylvainDemaimay, also take into account dynamic IP addresses, this is a common practice to allocate single IP address for the whole company's office and when you block just 1 person, noone else from this same office can access your site

Comment: @SylvainDemaimay, if this answer solves your issue do not forget to mark it as accepted, thanks.